# Debian Intel graphic drivers for nuc6i7kyk

Tags: debian, video

I have installed Debian Stretch on a nuc6i7kyk, but I cannot get the video drivers to work (I keep getting UNCLAIMED drivers).

Here as much info I can share on my install:

```
$ glxinfo | grep -i opengl
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.9, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 13.0.6
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 13.0.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 13.0.6
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:


$ lshw | grep UNCLAIMED
        *-display UNCLAIMED
        *-generic:0 UNCLAIMED
        *-generic:1 UNCLAIMED
                       *-usb UNCLAIMED
        *-memory UNCLAIMED

$ lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A 2
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Iris Pro Graphics 580 [8086:193b] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Iris Pro Graphics 580 [8086:2064]
    Kernel modules: i915

$ lshw -C video                               
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Iris Pro Graphics 580
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:db000000-dbffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Pro Graphics 580 (rev 09)

$ find /dev -group video
/dev/lirc0
/dev/fb0

$ lspci | grep VGA ; lsmod | grep "kms\|drm" ; find /dev -group video ; cat /proc/cmdline ; find /etc/modprobe.d/; cat /etc/modprobe.d/*kms* ; ls /etc/X11/xorg.conf ; glxinfo | grep -i "vendor\|rendering" ; grep LoadModule /var/log/Xorg.0.log
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Pro Graphics 580 (rev 09)
drm_kms_helper        155648  0
drm                   360448  1 drm_kms_helper
/dev/lirc0
/dev/fb0
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.9.0-6-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/giulio--provasi--vg-root ro quiet splash i915.enable_rc6 i915.alpha_support=1
/etc/modprobe.d/
/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/dkms.conf
# modprobe information used for DKMS modules
#
# This is a stub file, should be edited when needed,
# used by default by DKMS.
ls: cannot access '/etc/X11/xorg.conf': No such file or directory
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
    Vendor: VMware, Inc. (0xffffffff)
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
[     3.312] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     3.316] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[     3.316] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[     3.317] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[     3.324] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[     3.324] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[     3.324] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[     3.419] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
```

And kernel used (default 4.9.x, tried 4.15 too):

```
$ uname -mrs
Linux 4.9.0-6-amd64 x86_64

$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image   
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-0.bpo.2-amd64      4.15.11-1~bpo9+1                  amd64        Linux 4.15 for 64-bit PCs
ii  linux-image-4.9.0-6-amd64             4.9.82-1+deb9u3                   amd64        Linux 4.9 for 64-bit PCs
ii  linux-image-amd64                     4.15+91~bpo9+1                    amd64        Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)
```

And finally `xrandr` output:

```
$ xrandr --listmonitors
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Monitors: 1
 0: +default 2560/677x1440/381+0+0  default

$ xrandr --listactivemonitors
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Monitors: 1
 0: +default 2560/677x1440/381+0+0  default

$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 0

$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 2560 x 1440, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 2560 x 1440
default connected 2560x1440+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   2560x1440     93.00*
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thx.